# Do forward declarations disable any runtime optimizations?

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization, compiler-optimization, forward-declaration

We can forward declare a function:

```
void func1();

void func2() {
    // use func1
}

void func1() {
    // do stuff
}
```

This may be necessary if `func1` calls `func2`:

```
void func1();

void func2() {
    func1();
}

void func1() {
    if (condition) {
        func2();
    }
}
```

While inlining `func1` in the second example wouldn't be difficult, I do not know if in arbitrarily complicated programs there are theoretical barriers these kinds of compiler optimizations. In the second case, the forward declaration was necessary, and there may be compiler optimizations lost related to the recursive nature of the program.

**Question:** When forward declarations are not necessary but still used (e.g., the first example), are any compiler optimizations lost on any of the major compilers (gcc, clang, msvc)?

Comment: I don't think an unneeded forward declaration will have any effect on performance.

Comment: "Do forward declarations disable any runtime optimizations?" - No. Redundant forward declarations do not inhibit compiler optimizations (to the best of *my* knowledge).

Comment: Forward declarations should only affect the binary if they change the meaning of the code, e.g. forward declaring "a better match" to a function call.

Comment: Can the person who voted to close clarify what they are looking for to improve this question?

Comment: >Opens stack overflow question >Votes to close >Refuses to elaborate further >Leaves. Absolute Chad.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of *my* knowledge, redundant forward declarations do not inhibit any compiler optimizations. At worst, they present a couple extra tokens for the compiler to read and process and then discard (negligible).
There are situations where forward declarations can change the meaning of the code that follows and in such a situation that could, of course, have follow on effects on the compilers optimizer (but in such a case you are probably wanting the behaviour change, so not much you can do - it might even be a positive effect).

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify: my main concern was that there would be some Halting-Problem-style "the compiler can't prove things it would be nice to prove."

Comment: @MarkWallace I don't see how that would arise.

Comment: @MarkWallace: modern compilers like GCC and clang parse the whole translation unit before doing code-gen for any of the functions in it.  GCC `-funit-at-a-time` is on by default even at `-O0`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-funit-at-a-time  This answer is correct, if a declaration doesn't change the actual meaning of any code in functions, there won't be a difference in how it parses into logic for the compiler internals to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaring a function in the same translation unit (that is, the same cpp file) will not have any effect on performance. Modern compilers typically go through several passes (look into LLVM’s API if you’re interested) and will be able to see the definition, regardless of declarations, when generating backend instructions.

If functions are declared in multiple translation units, a compiler may or may not perform optimizations across unit boundaries. A compiler compiles each source file as a different translation unit, and, once all source files have been compiled as individuals (with only one source file containing the function definition) links them together. Optimizations between translation units is known as link-time optimization (LTO) and may or may not be enabled by default.

Ultimately, however, this should not be a significant concern. This sounds like a case of premature optimization — ideally, you should make a reasonable effort to write decent code, and optimize only when measured performance is below desired. Otherwise you’re likely to spend a significant amount of time trying to fix something that isn’t broken.